# How to track my Facebook share button with Google analytic

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I have this share button on my site:

```
.shr-btn-scl .facebookbtn{background-image:url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Odsu2qlGN6w/U4xV7l9bH-I/AAAAAAAACKE/hQLdHC9ZXJQ/w200-h49-no/face+un.png);display:block;
```

width:140px; height:30px; background-repeat:no-repeat;

```
<li><a class='facebookbtn' data-title='Facebook' expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;title=&quot;+ data:post.title' onclick='window.open(this.href, &apos;windowName&apos;, &apos;width=550, height=600, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable&apos;); return false;' rel='nofollow'/>
                    </li>
```

and i would like to track at least the number of clicks on it (independently from the fact that sharing is finalized or not). Can i track clicks on it with Google analytic?

Comment: Just because people didn't answer doesn't mean you should delete the old question and post a new one. The old one could be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214041/how-to-track-my-facebook-share-button-with-google-analytic-or-any-other-tracking?noredirect=1#comment37401812_24214041 before you deleted it

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for [Event Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'FBshareFollow', 1);"
```